# Golang for loop with 2 variables equivalent?

Tags: go

I am trying to understand golang's syntax in doc but some things are hard to understand even they explain it.

For example:

```
func Reverse(s string) string {
   r := []rune(s)
   for i, j := 0, len(r)-1; i < len(r)/2; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
    r[i], r[j] = r[j], r[i]
   }
   return string(r)
}
```

I translated it to raw code:

```
func reverseString2(str string) string {
    var array = []rune(str)
    for i := 0; i < len(str)/2; i++ {
        for j := len(str) - 1; ???? ; j-- {
          // ---
        }
    }
    return string(array)
}
```

my problem is that in the first one `for i, j := 0, len(r)-1; i < len(r)/2; i, j = i+1, j-1`, j does not seems to have a condition so in my code I dont know how to solve it.

Comment: These 2 are not equivalent: `i, j = i+1, j-1` this happens every iteration, both increments. You cannot really convert the first single loop to nested loops without changing the algorithm significantly.

Comment: how could the equivalent be like?

Comment: You cannot have _equivalent_ implementation with nested loops: it would be some completely different algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way that is easier to read and leads to the same result.
The only difference is that the scope of variable `j` has become different.

```golang
func Reverse(s string) string {
      r := []rune(s)
      j := len(r) - 1
      for i := 0; i < len(r)/2; i++ {
          r[i], r[j] = r[j], r[i]
          j--
      }
      return string(r)
}
```